# What is special/different about CyanogenMod's kernel? (especially compared to. DroidX GB kernel)

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-droid-x, kernel

In an [Phandroid article](http://phandroid.com/2011/06/13/despite-bootloader-woes-developer-gets-cyanogenmod-7-running-on-the-motorola-droid-x-video/) announcing the first successful attempt to run CyanogenMod on DroidX thanks to cvpcs's breakthrough, I noticed the following quote:

> CyanogenMod 7 will unfortunately be limited to running on the DROID X’s stock kernel.

Assuming that this is accurate, what (if any) of the main features of CM7 would be missing compared to normal phones' CM7?

In other words, which features of CM7 depend on CM7's own kernel code as opposed to non-kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CyanogenMod is a tweaked kernel. Because of this it's faster, since the team that make it work pretty hard to make Android more faster and stable as possible and also it's already rooted, so you don't need to go all over the process of rooting again.

I highly recommend you to check the [CyanogenMod Wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=What_is_CyanogenMod)

Comment: The kernel cannot be described as beeing "rooted". The distro (firmwarea) or recovery is "rooted" as a whole, not kernel.